# Parse simple JSON array using JSONArray

Tags: java, android, json

I'm new to use JSON format in Java and Android.  My result from server is :

```
["7405,test,3","7406,mahdi,1"]
```

with:

```
String archive_group = new JsonService ( G.config_username, G.config_password, G.F_GET_GROUP_ARCHIVE ).request ();
```

Now I want to parse this result and split with `,`.  My code is not correct.  Please help me to resolve that.

```
String archive_group = new JsonService ( G.config_username, G.config_password, G.F_GET_GROUP_ARCHIVE ).request ();
JSONArray data_array =  new JSONArray ( archive_group );
JSONArray json_obj = null;
for (int i = 0; i < data_array.length (); i++) {
    try {
        json_obj = data_array.getJSONArray ( i );
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace ();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        Log.e ( "json_obj", String.valueOf ( e ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: look at this example http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/json/java-json-parser-example/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an array full of String, not full of Array. Try this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < data_array.length (); i++) {
    try {
        String element = data_array.getString ( i );
        // Do whatever you want with element
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace ();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        Log.e ( "json_obj", String.valueOf ( e ) );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You put string value into json value so try

```
String value = data_array.getJSONArray ( i );
```

instead of

```
json_obj = data_array.getJSONArray ( i );
```